# Secure to save the instance state of a secure EditText?

Tags: android

Is it safe to store the contents of a secure `EditText` in the `saveInstanceState` bundle? It seems to me, this is a security hole. Rotate phone, collect other app’s password.

Comment: how would you gain access to another apps saveInstanceState? Regardless, you probably don't want to put anything into saved state that you don't want persisted to disk.

Comment: @NickCampion: I haven't seen that those bundles are persisted to disk. AFAIK, they are held in RAM by an OS process.

Comment: @CommonsWare that is probably right. I was thinking that some fragment or activity saved state bundles might be paged to disk. Thats probably not a safe assumption.

Comment: @NickCampion: At least with current Androids, there is no paging at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, that confirms many peoples' long held belief about assumptions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to store the contents of a secure EditText in the saveInstanceState bundle?

The only processes that have access to that `Bundle` are yours and the OS's. If you trust those processes, then it is safe.

> It seems to me, this is a security hole. Rotate phone, collect other app’s password.

You cannot access "other app's" `Bundle`. If you have proof to the contrary, submit an app demonstrating this effect to security@android.com.